# How to time a user's actions using server time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Here's what should happen on my quiz page:

1. User starts viewing a question.
2. The clock is started on him. (Start time saved in DB.)
3. User either ANSWERS or LEAVES.
4. The clock is stopped. (Quit time saved in DB.)

This is very easy for the first case, in which the user answers every question in sequence like a good little user. I can successfully set both a start time and a quit time.

However, if the user decides to leave the page in any way (even closing the entire the browser or throwing his computer out the window) I don't know how to keep track of that.

I'm thinking I could utilize DDP and whenever the connection breaks, I know the user is gone and can set a quit time. Problem is I don't know how to do that, or if it's even possible to make a method call or something like that when the user is already gone!

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Meteor.onConnection](https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#Meteor-onConnection) One of the parameters to the callback is an `onClose` callback that will execute as soon as the client closes the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) or [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) which are used in website analytics to get data from people who leave the page.